# How do to select specific date 'th' elements in an html file to webscrape in Python 3 using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am just trying to to scrape dates off of this web page https://www.history.navy.mil/content/history/nhhc/research/histories/ship-histories/us-ship-force-levels.html#1886

the dates are in 'th' elements and I am trying to just get the ones that contain a date. I guess maybe by using regular expressions?

I know this is a very easy thing to however, I can't find any tutorials or forum questions that match what I am trying to do.

Any help would be super appreciated :D

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re


r = requests.get('https://www.history.navy.mil/content/history/nhhc/research/histories/ship-histories/us-ship-force-levels.html#1886')


soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html.parser')

for table in soup.find_all('table'):
    for tr in table.find_all('tr'):
        for th in tr.find_all('th'):
            print(th.text)
```

This is a sample of my output so far:

```
DATE
12/86
12/87
12/88
12/89
12/90
12/91
BATTLESHIP
CRUISER*
MONITOR
TORPEDO BOATS
STEEL GUNBOATS**
AUXILIARIES
SCREW STEAMER***
```

I am basically just trying to grab these dates.

Comment: do you need to scrape the entire table, then just try pandas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you need to filter elements to get the date items, i would recommend lxml & xpath approach,

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml
from lxml import html

r = requests.get('https://www.history.navy.mil/content/history/nhhc/research/histories/ship-histories/us-ship-force-levels.html#1886')


tree = html.fromstring(r.content)
Dates = tree.xpath("//th[contains(.,'DATE')]/following-sibling::th/text()") 
print(Dates)
```

Comment: That did the trick, thanks so much. I am going to look into lxml now for webscraping! have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

There is a faster method with css selectors using :contains (bs4 4.7.1+)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://www.history.navy.mil/content/history/nhhc/research/histories/ship-histories/us-ship-force-levels.html#1886')
soup = bs(r.content,'lxml')
dates = [th.text for th in soup.select('th:contains(DATE) ~ th')]
print(dates)
```